# What's a good way to minimize bends in a dryer transition duct?

Tags: dryer, ducts

I installed a new clothes dryer yesterday using the laminated foil transition duct the appliance store gave me.  In order to get behind the dryer to access the duct, I have to pull the dryer out at least 4 feet from the wall.  Then when I push the dryer back to the wall, the duct lays in a twisted heap on the floor with lots of bends that could reduce efficiency and trap lint.

What tips do you have to minimize the number bends in the flexible duct?  Or, would you recommend a different type of transition duct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rigid duct would be best. But there are times where that is not so practical and flexible duct makes more sense. But you need to make sure that it is not any longer than it needs to be:

- Pull out the dryer
- Cut the flexible duct so that it is stretched and just long enough to reach (i.e., at an angle) with the dryer pulled out
- Push the dryer back in place

That should get it from "twisted heap" to "sag a bit on the floor but not too bad".

As far as rigid duct, depending on the layout of the room, you may be able to use an elbow plus one short (4' ?) piece to go from the dryer to an open spot just above the dryer and set up other rigid duct to meet it. Then when you push the dryer back in place you have two pieces that you can clamp together.

Comment: Would a semi-rigid duct likely work better than the laminated foil?

Comment: Not sure exactly what "semi rigid" is, but the more rigid the better, to avoid/minimize crushing, pinching, extra bends, lint collection, etc.

Comment: The semi-rigid kind is bendable, but it holds its shape when bent.  Example: https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-4-in-x-96-in-Aluminum-Semi-Rigid-Flexible-Duct/3134107

Comment: But be careful which one you use - that linked product specifically says **Do not use for dryer venting**

Comment: Good catch.  Here's a better example:  https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-Outdoor-Exhaust-Dryer-Vent-Kit/3308238

Comment: Better. But I'd connect it and then see how much slack there is and likely cut it down to fit better.